# Unable to add a background colour to the button in navigation

Tags: html, css, web

I am still an extreme beginner to web development and i am trying to create this navigation bar.

The issue i have come across is that the element i have floated to the right side is not on the same level as the other stuff.

This is probably due to something i have done with the css and  i can't pin it.

Also what i actually want to do is to change the background of the right floated element to pink and have a padding around it to make it look like a button. I dont know if i have gone about to do so in the right way . I did try to find it out on my own but havent had any luck so far.

This is my html.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WatchIT -Your one stop destination for all your movie tickets</title>            
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="navbar" class ="navbar-collapse">
            <ul>
                <li> <a class="active" href="" title="Home">HOME </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="" title="movies">MOVIES </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="" title="theaters">THEATERS </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="" title="tickets">BUY TICKETS ONLINE </a> </li>
                <li style="float:right"><a class="btn btn-scope1 navbar-btn" href="">TEST YOUR KNOWLEDGE </a> </li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is my css.

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #00004d;
    font-size:15px
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #000080;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #00abbd;
    outline: none; 
}

.btn-scope1 {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding:4px 15px;
    font-weight:600;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
    min-width: 100px;
}

.btn-scope:hover {
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.9;
    background-color: rgba(238, 12, 110, 0.8); 
}
```

Please be kind enough to ignore my ignorance on certain things that i may have put on.What i honestly want is to have a padding in pink like the "Post your question button" on stackoverflow on the buytickets and test your knowledge button. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your issue is twofold: One, using margins and two, using a background to style your button. The simplest change is as follows:

In your css, change:

```
.btn-scope1 {
text-transform:uppercase;
padding:10px 1px;
margin-right: 30px;
margin-top: 5px;
background: red;
font-weight:600;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-ms-border-radius: 3px; 
border-radius: 3px;
font-size: 10px;
min-width: 100px;
}
```

The background will give you the required button background effect. What's important to note is the margin you set. This will enable you to move around the concerned element with respect to the div it is placed in.

Here's [a link.](https://codepen.io/mayya_rohan/pen/gKQxwg) (Codepen to show desired result.)

Comment: Hello , thank you so much this helped. What i didnt know was the alignment from the margins it seems you pointed it out. I didnt realise it i was too bothered looking into the padding and backgrounds probably explains my knowledge on web . Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Please check again whether this is what you need

```css
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #00004d;
 font-size:15px
 }

li {
float: left;
 }

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #000080;
}

a:active {
text-decoration: none;
color: #00abbd;
outline: none; 
 }
 .btn-scope1 {

 text-transform:uppercase;
 padding:4px 15px;
 font-weight:600;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
 -ms-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
 font-size: 12px;
 min-width: 100px;
 }
.btn-scope:hover {
 color: #fff;
 opacity: 0.9;
 background-color: rgba(238, 12, 110, 0.8); }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WatchIT -Your one stop destination for all your movie tickets</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    </head>



            <div id="navbar" class ="navbar-collapse">

            <ul>
                <li> <a class="active" href="" title="Home">HOME </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="" title="movies">MOVIES </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="" title="theaters">THEATERS </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="" title="tickets">BUY TICKETS ONLINE </a> </li>
                <li style="float:right;padding:15px;"><a class="btn btn-scope1 navbar-btn" href="" style="background-color:pink !important;">TEST YOUR KNOWLEDGE </a> </li>

            </ul>   

            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.scopecinemas.com/movies take a look at this website , the button in the pink that is what i want to create

Comment: If any other specification then tell me with your code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: select elements by class or id selector. try to avoid inline styling

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on starting web development.

A simple fix for this issue is to give the elements you want to style an ID like `<a href="" id="link1">Link Text</a>` and then style it with the ID-selector in CSS like `#link1 { backgroundcolor: red; }`, ideally you should give a class in the HTML selector, like `<a href="" class="link">Class</a>` and then style it with `.link {backgroundcolor: red}`.

Answer (score 0):

That is happening becuase you are providing separate padding values through `btn-scope1`. Remove that part, et voila!

Here's the css after removing that part.

```
.btn-scope1 {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    /*padding:4px 15px;*/
    font-weight:600;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
    min-width: 100px;
}
```