# changing the text color according to the active tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

Following my question posted here
[Unable to add a background colour to the button in navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080542/unable-to-add-a-background-colour-to-the-button-in-navigation)

I have managed to fix my issues and move on with my work, however, an issue I came across was to change the font color of the navigation bar elements according to the active tab. The "currently active" tab is given the correct color through CSS so I'm hoping the CSS part is correct thus leaving the JavaScript part an issue.

```js
var header = document.getElementById("navbar");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("topnavbar");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
 .active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #4da6ff;
    outline: none;  
 }
```

```html
<div id="navbar" >
   <ul>
       <li> <a class="topnavbar active" href="" id="home"title="Home">HOME </a> </li>
       <li> <a class="topnavbar"        href="" id="movies" title="Movies">MOVIES </a> </li>
       <li> <a class="topnavbar"        href="" id="theaters" title="Theaters">THEATERS </a></li>
       <li> <a class="topnavbar"        href="" id="buytickets" title="Buy Tickets Online">BUY TICKETS ONLINE </a> </li>
       <li style="float:right"><a class="btn btn-scope1 navbar-btn" id="btn1" href="">TEST YOUR KNOWLEDGE </a> </li> 
    </ul> 
</div>
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bera967h/ This seems to work for me.

Comment: am not what exactly you are trying to achieve, but your active color seems to be working perfectly alright

Comment: Everything seems like it's working fine. What are you trying to fix?

Comment: @jismon  well in that case it is over shadowed by another css element i am using because for me it doesnt work and i can not pin why it doesnt this is my entire css.I have reuploaded it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below, i have pasted your exact code, it seems to be working fine, all i did was adding # on your href so that it stays on the same page.

```js
var header = document.getElementById("navbar");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("topnavbar");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
 .active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #4da6ff;
    outline: none;
    background: #34495e;
 }
```

```html
<div id="navbar" >
   <ul>
       <li> <a class="topnavbar active" href="#" id="home"title="Home">HOME </a> </li>
       <li> <a class="topnavbar"        href="#" id="movies" title="Movies">MOVIES </a> </li>
       <li> <a class="topnavbar"        href="#" id="theaters" title="Theaters">THEATERS </a></li>
       <li> <a class="topnavbar"        href="#" id="buytickets" title="Buy Tickets Online">BUY TICKETS ONLINE </a> </li>
       <li style="float:right"><a class="btn btn-scope1 navbar-btn" id="btn1" href="">TEST YOUR KNOWLEDGE </a> </li> 
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: can you try opening it on a web browser , it doesnt work for me idk why the "home" gets the correct color but upon pressing movies it doesnt change home remains as the color blue

Comment: I think something is wrong in how i put it together, i am trying to use external Style sheet and external JS. Cz like you said the code i have uploaded seem to be working on tools , but when i put it accordingly as external style sheets it doesnt  work on my Pc. I tried it on 3browsers

Comment: @anjulaserasinghe, if you can post your entire code in fiddle or code pen, I might be able to help you

Comment: Hello i managed to fix it , for some reason me using the script inside head didnt work and it had to be used inside the body instead. I referred to w3schools and it said that it can be used in the head tag as well but the browser doesnt detect the tags. Thank you so much for the time you put in for me

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it . Like you all said , what I had done was right but the issue was where i tried to use the script tag. I read in an article where it was said that using the script tag inside the `<head>` tag was correct. But for some reason it seems to give a negative effect. After re used it inside the body tag it worked. Sorry for the trouble caused by me. Thank you for those who took time to help me.